# How to select one and remove correlated features from a long format correlation dataframe directly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long format pandas dataframe containing feature correlation pairs (with duplicate pairs). I want to select one out of every correlated pair from this long table (100s of feature). Is their a pythonic way to do this without transforming this table into a matrix? Ideally in this example, we need to keep only feature `a`, since it is correlated to both `b` and `c`. In this example, I'm considering the threshold 0.95.

| feature1 | feature2 | corr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 0.96 |
| b | a | 0.96 |
| a | c | 0.95 |
| c | a | 0.95 |
| b | c | 0.94 |
| c | b | 0.94 |

Reproduce this dataframe using

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c'],
                   'feature2': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c'],
                   'corr': [0.96, 0.96, 0.95, 0.95, 0.94, 0.94]})
```

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean *"without transforming this table into a matrix"*, it already is one.

Comment: yes, managed to work this out by sorting the rows, posted the answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by lexicographical sorting the rows and then removing everything from `feature2` column.

```
features_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def custom_sort(x):
    min_val = min(x["feature1"], x["feature2"])
    max_val = max(x["feature1"], x["feature2"])
    x["feature1"] = min_val
    x["feature2"] = max_val
    return x

drop_features_list = list(df.apply(custom_sort, axis=1)["feature2"].drop_duplicates())
drop_features_list

selected_features = list(set(features_list) - set(drop_features_list))
selected_features
> ['a']
```